# What is sci-fi stackexchange's stance on ideologically motivated questions?

Tags: discussion

My title pretty much encapsulates my concern.

Are questions that are blatantly ideologically motivated (extreme example:  "Why is Tolkien's portrayal of the westerlings so racist?") a problem or are they considered appropriate?

Comment: Do you mean *easterlings*? :-)

Comment: Derp @Randal'Thor.  I don't Tolkien very well

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer to this one is extremely simple. By all means ask your question, but *avoid the [colour commentary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_commentator).*

For the record, someone already asked the question in your example. It did attract some downvotes, but was largely well-received, mostly because it avoided making any direct assertions.

- [Is Tolkien prejudiced against the East?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/18304/is-tolkien-prejudiced-against-the-east)

Comment: (1) It was not "well recieved with some downvotes" - it has, deservedly, gotten 18 downvotes. (2)  It was "well recieved" likely not because of some inherent quality of the question because liberals like to make Westerners sound bad (and HNQ, which has upvote bias regardless of topic, on top of which from my observation most SO traffic on HNQ questions tends left wing politically). (3) It most certainly was NOT because it "avoided making direct assertions", it very explicitly made them by saying "as a Westerner, he was a racist") which I just edited out as being contrary to Be Nice rule.

Comment: @DVK-ON-ahch-To - My interpretation was perhaps a bit more generous.  I felt that every was asking "Is Tolkien a racist" rather than asserting that he is.

Comment: the problem wasn't in asking whether Tolkien is a racist (there's a valid basis to ask that, given surface reading of the text). It was the now-deleted  "as a Westerner, he was a racist" assertion.